# How to change cVLC prompt?

Tags: prompt, vlc, cvlc

I use `cvlc`, that is command-line version of VLC media player a lot.

It has default prompt of '`>`' sign.

I wonder if it is changeable, and if it is how can I reconfigure it ?

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found it myself through the `set` command in `cvlc` shell, it is `set prompt <value>`.

It also can be done via:

`vlc -I cli --lua-config "cli={prompt='<value>'}"`